# C->C++ Automatically cast void pointer into Type pointer in C++ in #define in case of type is not given (C-style) [MSVS]

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, casting, void-pointers

**Hi!**

I've used the following **C** macro, But in **C++** it can't automatically cast `void*` to `type*`.

```
#define MALLOC_SAFE(var, size) { \
    var = malloc(size); \
    if (!var) goto error; \
}
```

I know, I can do something like this:

```
#define MALLOC_SAFE_CPP(var, type, size) { \
    var = (type)malloc(size); \
    if (!var) goto error; \
}
```

But I don't want to rewrite a big portion of code, where `MALLOC_SAFE` was used.

Is there any way to do this without giving the type to the macro? Maybe some **MSVC 2005** `#pragma`/`__declspec`/other ?

p.s.: I can't use C compiler, because my code is part (one of hundreds modules) of the large project. And now it's on C++. I know, I can build my code separately. But it's old code and I just want to port it fast.

The question is about void* casting ;) If it's not possible, I'll just replace MACRO_SAFE with MACRO_SAFE_CPP

**Thank You!**

Comment: How is your memory freed?  using `free` directly, or a macro?

Comment: Why can't you compile the code as a C program?  Visual C++ will compile C.

Comment: So wait, you're programming C and cannot use a C compiler? What?

Comment: @zxcat: Which version of MSVC?

Comment: The C++ compilers I'm familiar with compile C as well, if the file is specified as C.  In the meantime, if you're replacing the macro, you might consider changing to `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to do this, that's why I'm not providing it as an answer, just a consideration.  Would it really be that bad to rewrite the code?  I mean, it's terrible even as C code.  It certainly doesn't belong in a C++ program.  If it were me, even if it took a few full working days to rewrite it, I would do it.  In my time off if I had to.

Comment: @PigBen: yes, I know, it's terrible. And of course I'll rewrite it

Comment: @zxcat:  You will?  You know I was referring to the "big portion of code, where MALLOC_SAFE was used.", which you said you didn't want to rewrite, not just the macro itself, right?

Comment: @PigBen: yes, I don't want to rewrite it now. Now I want to compile it and use as fast as possible. But I see the code is bad. Not only with this macro. Later the whole module will be rewritten.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**I do not recommend doing this; this is terrible code and if you are using C you should compile it with a C compiler (or, in Visual C++, as a C file)**

If you are using Visual C++, you can use `decltype`:

```
#define MALLOC_SAFE(var, size)                      \
{                                                   \
    var = static_cast<decltype(var)>(malloc(size)); \
    if (!var) goto error;                           \
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @James. This is the answer I've searched. Bad, that vs2010 only

Comment: On another note, a macro should never be `{ ... }`, it's much safer to use `do { ... } while(0)` instead. It will behave much better with any trailing `;` you might have and `if else` blocks.

Answer (score 37):

To makes James' answer even dirtier, if you don't have `decltype` support you can also do this:

```
template <typename T>
class auto_cast_wrapper
{
public:
    template <typename R>
    friend auto_cast_wrapper<R> auto_cast(const R& x);

    template <typename U>
    operator U()
    {
        return static_cast<U>(mX);
    }

private:
    auto_cast_wrapper(const T& x) :
    mX(x)
    {}

    auto_cast_wrapper(const auto_cast_wrapper& other) :
    mX(other.mX)
    {}

    // non-assignable
    auto_cast_wrapper& operator=(const auto_cast_wrapper&);

    const T& mX;
};

template <typename R>
auto_cast_wrapper<R> auto_cast(const R& x)
{
    return auto_cast_wrapper<R>(x);
}
```

Then:

```
#define MALLOC_SAFE(var, size)                      \
{                                                   \
    var = auto_cast(malloc(size));                  \
    if (!var) goto error;                           \
}
```

Don't use it for anything but evil.

Comment: +1 for the first real solution I've seen to C++'s broken `void *` behavior.

Comment: @R.:  What broken `void *` behavior in C++?  Given that it's a statically typed language, I have to approve any movement toward type safety, and you rarely need a `void *` in C++ anyway.

Comment: I upvoted it, it's just too perverted to not upvote. If you downvote we can split the difference and say we both gave it half a vote each way ;)

Comment: Also as David says, I don't see what's "broken" about a statically typed language requiring you to respect the static type system. I know some people don't like to hear this, but it is possible for languages to be different than C **and at the same time not be broken**.

Comment: Heh, It's works (at least compiles). And with `inline` added produces good (without any overhead) asm code :)

Comment: As a personal rule, I never follow a link named "how perverted."  This is the Internet; I don't even want to think of what might be at that link...

Comment: @GMan: Also will this work if friend functions 'T' is a built-in type (void * always?). In that case ADL will fail isn't it and hence friend function (auto_cast) won't be found? Sorry, but I am having trouble understanding this.

Comment: I <3 GMan. Is there a reason you used `const R&` instead of forcing it to only work with void*?

Comment: @acid: Just generality, for the fun of it. I prefer generic utilities being used in specific cases over specific utilities for specific cases; the former allows re-usability.

Comment: I can't imagine where ELSE this SHOULD be used. Hence my question >: -). But then again I never use typecasting (except mallocs)

Comment: @acid: Oh I don't know where to use it either, lol, I just do it anyway.

Comment: To bad it doesnt work with single parameter constructors http://www.pastie.org/1890862
I dont think there is a way to get that to work

Comment: @acid: The reason for that is that it's not sure what overload to pick: the user-defined constructor or the copy-constructor, even though with the normal value overload resolution works. (You might think to use `enable_if` and `is_convertible` on the conversion operator, but the template argument isn't known until *after* the overload is picked.) I can't think of a way either.

Answer (score 5):

For example, like this:

```
template <class T>
void malloc_safe_impl(T** p, size_t size)
{
    *p = static_cast<T*>(malloc(size));
}

#define MALLOC_SAFE(var, size) { \
    malloc_safe_impl(&var, size); \
    if (!var) goto error; \
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason nobody just casts ***var***, your argument to SAFE_MALOC()?  I mean, ***malloc()*** returns a pointer.  You're storing it somewhere that accepts a pointer...  There are all sorts of neat type-safe things that other folks have already pointed out...  I'm just wondering why this didn't work:

```
#define MALLOC_SAFE(var,size)  {  \
    (* (void **) & (var)) = malloc(size); \
    if ( ! (var) ) goto error;    \
    }
```

Yeah...  I know.  It's sick, and throws type-safety right out the window.  But a straight ***((void *)(var))=*** cast wouldn't always work.