# Making auto_cast safe

Tags: c++, casting

[GMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gman) has posted a code for the [delicious `auto_cast` “operator”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027734/87234) that allows to write code such as the following in C++:

```
float f = 4.0f;
int i = auto_cast(f);
// instead of:
int j = static_cast<int>(f);
```

or, more saliently,

```
T x = value;
typename nested_type<with, template_arguments>::type y = auto_cast(x);
// instead of
typedef typename nested_type<with, template_arguments>::type my_type;
my_type z = static_cast<my_type>(x);
```

Basically, the operator is great in removing unnecessary redundancy from a `static_cast`, and at the same time is still *safe*. It’s even *more* safe than `static_cast` since it prevents accidentally mismatching the types:

```
int i = 1234;
short s = static_cast<char>(i); // s == -46, not 1234!
```

However, [j_random_hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47984/j-random-hacker) has noticed a flaw in the operator:

> static_cast allows downcasts, which are potentially unsafe.

Indeed, an `auto_cast` should probably forbid downcasts because they may fail:

```
class base { };
class derived : public base { };

base b;
derived* pd = auto_cast(&b); // should fail at compile time.
```

Hence my question:

**How would you modify the `auto_cast` implementation in order to forbid downcasts?**
This will probably involve `enable_if`. I’m especially interested in a solution that allows the compiler to provide good diagnostics in case of failure (= readable error messages).

Comment: Note that `auto_cast` is not able to perform a downcast by reference semantics. It will always copy the source. That sounds safe to me: If the class you "downcast" to has no constructor accepting a base class object, it will simply fail to compile, just as if you used enable_if, but I imagine you would get even better errors, because if you use enable_if on the conversion function, you would get something like *"cannot convert auto_cast_wrapper<BaseClass&> to DerivedClass"*. If you leave it unchanged I think you may get *"Cannot static_cast Base& to DerivedClass"*.

Comment: @Johannes I was concerned with *pointers* to classes. `base b; derived* d = auto_cast(&b);` will unfortunately compile just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you want to use the `T{u}` form of initialization.

```
template <typename U>
operator U()
{
    return U{std::forward<T>(mX)};
}
```

One of the reasons for these uniform initialization was that to use explicit constructors for creating a temporary, you need a cast aka `T(u)`. With `T{u}` that problem was solved. For C++03, I imagine you could do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct construct_explicit {
  template<typename U>
  construct_explicit(U &u):t(u) { }
  template<typename U>
  construct_explicit(U const &u):t(u) { }

  T &get() { return t; }
  T const& get() const { return t; }

  T t;
};
```

Then you can say `construct_explicit<U>(mX).get()`, although in a case like in your conversion function, it also works to use a named variable as an intermediary step, I think

```
template <typename U>
operator U()
{
    // or C++03: U u(mX);
    U u(std::forward<T>(mX));
    return u;
}
```

Comment: We have a winner. That solution seems perfect. Now `auto_cast` just needs to be renamed to `explicit_cast` (actually, I still prefer `auto_cast` …).

Comment: @Konrad: In what way is that cast explicit? :P

Comment: @Xeo It’s explicit because we have to write it (as opposed to an implicit cast operator). The name would come from the fact that this code is using the `explicit` constructor of a class.

Comment: TBH, I don't quite understand how that solves the problem of downcasting as @Konrad states in his question.

Comment: @Xeo Try compiling the downcast code example from my question … it won’t work any longer.

Comment: @Konrad: Ah, I see now how that solution works. :) Nice with relying on the language itself and not some TMP hackery.

Comment: @Xeo `Derived *t(baseptr)` doesn't work. But `HasExplicitCtor c(usesExplicitCtor);` works fine. The `T{u}` form of initialization "roughly" is similar to constructing a temporary by `T t(u)` and then using `t` as the result of the temporary (there is a difference for c++0x, in that `T{u}` first considers initializer-list constructors, and that it works when `T` is an aggregate but `T t(u)` doesn't... But both will not allow non-implicit conversions).

Comment: In this way, perhaps using `T{u}` isn't really the way to go, because it will also make `struct A { int b; }; A a = auto_cast(1);` work. In that case, you can use `construct_explicit` or use a named variable initialized using parens.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I forgot for a moment that base pointer can't implicitly be casted to derived pointer. :)

Comment: @Xeo it turns out that C++0x' `std::is_constructible` checks against this exact thing: Allow explicit constructors or explicit conversion functions, but forbid the casts like downcasts etc.

Comment: so `template<typename U, typename=typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<U,T&&>>::type operator U()&& { return U(std::forward<T>(t)); }` to explicitly and safely construct and avoid initializer lists?  Still requires a copy/move constructor.  `return {}` doesn't work, because it doesn't call explicit ctors.

Comment: Frequently I need to assign a value of type `uint64_t` into a structure member that may be of type `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`, depending on the platform. I would prefer not to use `static_cast<uint32_t>` since this adds unnecessary run-time overhead on the platforms where this structure member is of type `uint64_t`. In this situation `auto_cast` is almost perfect except that it emits a warning about the narrowing conversion. To solve this, I have [extended](https://github.com/whitslack/common/blob/b15cb66d2f41ed9/auto_cast.h) the solution given here to support warning-free narrowing conversions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use type-traits to disable the operator if `T` is a base of `R`. As we're in C++0x, you can explicitly `static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, "Cannot auto_cast downwards!");`

Comment: I'd prefix that `is_base_of` with a `!`. :)

Comment: @Xeo And put a `remove_pointer` around the types, and test for `is_pointer` beforehand. ;-) Then it works and gives very nice diagnostics. But Johannes’ answer is better still.

Comment: It appears `std::is_constructible` does the desired thing.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't even use auto_cast because static_cast, const_cast, dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast are also made ugly by design to help pointing code that could need refactoring : a ugly operation should have an ugly look.

> A secondary reason for introducing the
>   new-style cast was that C-style casts
>   are very hard to spot in a program.
>   For example, you can't conveniently
>   search for casts using an ordinary
>   editor or word processor. This
>   near-invisibility of C-style casts is
>   especially unfortunate because they
>   are so potentially damaging. An ugly
>   operation should have an ugly
>   syntactic form. That observation was
>   part of the reason for choosing the
>   syntax for the new-style casts. A
>   further reason was for the new-style
>   casts to match the template notation,
>   so that programmers can write their
>   own casts, especially run-time checked
>   casts.

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#static-cast

I prefer to see clearly in the code where it could be better, or where we explicitely need to make this ugly operation.

Comment: You’re of course right in general. However I believe that the situations in which `auto_cast` would be used are (1) relatively safe and (2) a necessity. Casts in general should be avoided, true, but this isn’t always possible.

Comment: Yes but then they should be remarkable. auto_cast hides remarkable side of writing the other casts.

Comment: What do you mean by “auto_cast hides remarkable side of writing the other casts”? FWIW I think that an `auto_cast` stands out sufficiently – compared to `static_cast` it merely removes the redundancy of having to input the target type *twice*, where once would suffice. So whether I write `T y = static_cast<T>(x);` or `T y = auto_cast(x);` isn’t that important. The important thing is that I don’t write `T y = x;` or `T y = something(x)` where `something` does not imply that a cast is being made. The good thing about `auto_cast` is that the name clearly tells what’s happening: a cast.

Comment: So it's more meant to replace auto y = static_cast<thing>(x); ? Then yes it's useful if you don't have auto available.