# Which is the idiomatic way to document a static_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I understand that `(MyType)foo`, `MyType(foo)`, and `static_cast<MyType>(foo)` are somewhat similar in that the first two become the last (EDIT: I have been corrected. The previous sentence is untrue.) My question is which is the idiomatic version to use? Is context a consideration?

Since I know that C style casts are not preferred in C++, it is down to functional casts and static_cast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx

Comment: No, these are *not* the same. For example, the first one becomes a `reinterpret_cast`, not a `static_cast`.

Comment: The fact that you can grep `static_cast` makes it a winner in my eyes.

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't MyType(foo) call a constructor?

Comment: I'd say in C++ it's idiomatic to use the correct cast for the situation. As far as I know, that should always be one of `static`, `reinterpret`, `dynamic` or `const`. But never a functional-style cast or C-style cast.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It does. The remaining two also do.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that the C style cast could result in any number of casts. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two, `(MyType)foo` and `MyType(foo)`, have the same meaning. What the meaning is depends a lot on `MyType` and the type of `foo`. So for example:

```
((int)1.0);   // a static_cast
int i = 0;
((char*)&i);  // a reinterpret_cast
const int j = 0;
((int*)&j);   // a const_cast
((char*)&j);  // a combination of a const_cast and a reinterpret_cast

typedef char *CharPtr;
CharPtr(&j);  // a C-style cast, same as ((CharPtr)&j) or ((char*)&j)
```

So the reason C-style casts are not preferred is that C-style casts do a lot of different things. C++ provides means to distinguish between them. In a lot of cases that makes it easier to understand the code, especially once you're writing generic code in C++ and the types are less obvious than they typically are in C.

So that's why `static_cast` etc are preferred in C++ -- they lay out explicitly for the reader something that might otherwise be difficult for them to work out for themselves. `static_cast` also does a few different things, by the way, so in principle you might want even more different casts. But `static_cast` at least does less than a C-style cast.

Functional-style casts with one argument *are* C-style casts. They are explicitly defined in the standard to mean exactly the same thing, in all cases.

Now, there are some cases where you might accept a C-style cast when written in the functional syntax but not when written with the C cast syntax. This is generally when the destination type is a class and it's obvious which constructor will be called. In a case like that, `std::vector<int>(0)` is shorter than `static_cast<std::vector<int>>(0)`, and generally clearer since it can be read as a constructor call. But it still has the same "dangers" as writing `(std::vector<int>)0`. If you were to write every conversion that way then eventually you'd accidentally remove `const` from a pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

Using an explicit cast is idiomatic in my book.

`static_cast<MyType>(foo)` is better than `(MyType)foo` because it is more expressive and explicit.  This is especially useful in the many cases where the `(MyType)foo` *doesn't* mean what you expect it to mean.  For example, in your examples these cases might not reduce to `static_cast` at all, but `reinterpret_cast`.

In a code review, I would reject every and all C-style casts on non-arithmetic types.

Comment: I'd allow them for arithmetic types. I don't think that `std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));` is any better than `std::tolower((unsigned char)c);`. The destination type is enough to ensure it can't remove const or anything else scary. But if you need a very simple rule, then it has to be to forbid them. IIRC there's also some stupid thing that can only be done with a C-style cast but that in almost all circumstances you have no business doing anyway. Casting a pointer to a pointer-to-private-base or something.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  I wasn't really thinking of arithmetic types.  I suppose I more or less agree with you.  Less in the sense that the type of `i` might be changed in the future, but that seems a little fantastical.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Right.

Comment: sorry, deleted the comment from under you. I had a sudden panic what would happen if it changed to a pointer type (you'd want the code to fail to compile since even though the `tolower` call is "safe" it's meaningless), but I don't have time to check right now :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Right again, but like I said earlier, it seems a bit fantastical.  FWIW, I do use explicit casts for arithmetic types, but I don't reject C-style casts on them in a code review.  I may start doing the latter.  Better always safe than very rarely sorry, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

First, while new to C++, functional style casts *are* C-style casts.  They do the same thing.

C-style casts first try to `static_cast`, and if that doesn't work, does a `reinterpret_cast`<sup>1</sup>.  This is bad, because operations that are intended to be a simple change can become very strange.

As an example, suppose you have a `Foo* f` and a completely unrelated class `Bar`.  You can `(Bar*)f` and it will silently reinterpret the `*f` to be a `Bar`, likely leading to undefined behavior.

A `static_cast` would only work in this situation if `Foo` and `Bar` were related types.

Now, even `static_cast` can be too strong, so I often write up an `implicit_cast` or `non_cast` template that converts-without-casting.  Similarly, I write `as_const` that adds `const` rather than requiring a `const_cast` (which can both add and remove `const`, and removing `const` is far more dangerous than adding it).

It is somewhat annoying that there is no explicit safe cast in C++, and I do not know how to write one (one that will execute `explicit` constructors, but will not cast "down" a type hierarchy like `static_cast` will).

---

<sup>1</sup> this is an over-simplification, but close enough to true.

Comment: "there is no explicit safe cast in C++" -- hmm. A template function that does a `static_cast` and is disabled where both template parameters are pointer types and (after `remove_pointer`) the source is a base of the destination?

Comment: @SteveJessop "upward" pointer casts are also safe, so ya.  And SFINAE will probably work.  Does that catch every case?

Comment: Btw, a web search for “C++ explicit_cast” led me there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693432/making-auto-cast-safe (in short, C++11 uniform initialization and `std::is_constructible` were evoked)