# swap() for custom type in C++: use ADL or template specialization?

Tags: c++, swap, argument-dependent-lookup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to provide a swap function for my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380862/how-to-provide-a-swap-function-for-my-class)

*Similar questions (e.g. [How to overload std::swap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap)) have been asked here, but I still don't see a conclusive answer.*

From various sources I know of two recommended (by different people) ways of extending `swap()` for custom types:

- write a free function in the same namespace and have [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) look it up;
- specialize `std::swap()` template for your type.

The first way looks a bit more elegant, however there's a problem with it I don't see how to overcome:

```
template <typename type>
struct my_type
{
  type  field;
  void swap (my_type& that)
  {
    std::swap (this->field, that.field);  // what to do to use ADL?
  }
};
```

In the snippet above `my_type` has a `swap()` member, similar to stdlib containers; note that it's *not* a replacement for free function, let's say I just want to have it.  Now, the problem is with the commented line, swapping two `field`s.  Since `type` can be anything, I'd like to use `swap()` customized for that `type`, not the generic variant.  However, I can't (it seems) use ADL, because if I remove `std::`, compiler always chooses the member function which is, obviously, not suitable for `type`.  And if I leave `std::` there, any customizations of `swap()` relying on ADL are bypassed, while specializations of `std::swap()` can still be used.

Won't the above usecase defeat all ADL customization of `swap()` algorithm?  Or is it still possible to use ADL lookup for `swap()` inside a class with `swap()` member?

Comment: See my answer in that question, 1) is how you should use / enable ADL swap.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed answers it.