# Move semantics == custom swap function obsolete?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, move-semantics, obsolete

Recently, [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380862/how-to-provide-a-swap-function-for-my-class) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402463/swap-for-custom-type-in-c-use-adl-or-template-specialization) [pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414196/how-to-add-stdswap-for-my-template-class) on how to provide your own `swap` function. With C++11, `std::swap` will use `std::move` and move semantics to swap the given values as fast as possible. This, of course, only works if you provide a move constructor and a move assignment operator (or one that uses pass-by-value).

Now, with that given, is it actually necessary to write your own `swap` functions in C++11? I could only think of non-movable types, but then again, the custom `swap`s usually work through some kind of "pointer exchange" (aka moving). Maybe with certain reference variables? Hm...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a matter of judgment.  I will typically let `std::swap` do the job for prototyping code, but for release code write a custom swap.  I can usually write a custom swap that is about twice as fast as 1 move construction + 2 move assignments + 1 resourceless destruction.  However one may want to wait until `std::swap` actually proves to be a performance problem before going to the bother.

**Update for Alf P. Steinbach:**

20.2.2 [utility.swap] specifies that `std::swap(T&, T&)` has a `noexcept` equivalent to:

```
template <class T>
void
swap(T& a, T& b) noexcept
                 (
                    is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
                    is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value
                 );
```

I.e. if move operations on `T` are `noexcept`, then `std::swap` on `T` is `noexcept`.

Note that this spec doesn't require move members.  It only requires that construction and assignment from rvalues exists, and if it is `noexcept`, then swap will be `noexcept`.  E.g.:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const A&) noexcept;
    A& operator=(const A&) noexcept;
};
```

`std::swap<A>` is noexcept, even without move members.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Howard. I'm guessing that `A(const A&) noexcept;` is a typo, or perhaps SO swallowing ampersands? I.e. that you meant `A(A&&) noexcept;` (and ditto for the assignment opperator)? Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: No; he is giving an example where `std::swap` will be `noexcept(true)` even without actual move construction/assignment.

Comment: @Dennis: I think I need more explanation then, because to me that looks like an ordinary (not move) copy constructor, and an ordinary copy assignment operator, and as I understand it those have nothing to do with `is_nothrow_move_constructible` or `is_nothrow_move_assignable`?

Comment: @Alf: `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>` is the same as `is_nothrow_constructible<T, T&&>`. The traditional `T(const T&)` version of the copy constructor accepts an r-value reference just fine, so `T` will report as being move constructible, even if an actual move does not take place.  A similar mapping is performed from `is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>` to `is_nothrow_assignable<T, T&&>`, so the same argument applies there.

Comment: @Dennis:  Thanks for the explanation to everyone, you're exactly correct.  I'm just now getting back to this.

Comment: hmm i cannot find that "duck bug" footnote in n3290.

Comment: Search for "duck" on this page. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can implement swap as

```
template <class T>
void swap(T& x, T& y)
{
  T temp = std::move(x);
  x = std::move(y);
  y = std::move(temp);
}
```

But we might have our own class, say `A`, which we can swap more quickly.

```
void swap(A& x, A& y)
{
  using std::swap;
  swap(x.ptr, y.ptr);
}
```

Which, instead of having to run a constructor and destructor, just swaps the pointers (which may well be implemented as XCHG or something similar).

Of course, the compiler might optimize out the constructor/destructor calls in the first example, but if they have side effects (i.e. calls to new/delete) it may not be smart enough to optimize them away.

Comment: If your move constructor/assignment operator have side effects not reflected in your custom swap, I suspect you've implemented them wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some types that can be swapped but not moved. I don't know of any non-movable types, so I don't have any examples.

Comment: std::array<int> are copyable but have no move constructor, if that's what you meant.

Comment: A non-movable thing: `CRITICAL_SECTION` from Win32 API looks like one. It's an opaque type, it must be initialized, it cannot be copied, and it has a pointer to itself inside. Movable wrapper around one would have to have a pointer to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

By convention a custom `swap` offers no-throw guarantee. I don't know about `std::swap`. My impression of the committee's work on that is that it was all political, so it would not surprise me if they somewhere had defined `duck` as `bug`, or similar political word-game maneuvers. So I would not rely on *any answer here* unless it provides a detailed blow by blow quoting from the C++0x to-be-standard, down the smallest detail (so as to be sure no `bug`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following class that holds a memory-allocated resource (for simplicity, represented by a single integer number):

```
class X {
    int* i_;
public:
    X(int i) : i_(new int(i)) { }
    X(X&& rhs) noexcept : i_(rhs.i_) { rhs.i_ = nullptr; }
 // X& operator=(X&& rhs) noexcept { delete i_; i_ = rhs.i_;
 //                                  rhs.i_ = nullptr; return *this; }
    X& operator=(X rhs) noexcept { swap(rhs); return *this; }
    ~X() { delete i_; }
    void swap(X& rhs) noexcept { std::swap(i_, rhs.i_); }
};

void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs) { lhs.swap(rhs); }
```

Then `std::swap` results in **deleting null pointer 3 times** (both for *move assignment operator* and *unifying assignment operator* cases). Compilers might have problem to optimize out such a `delete`, see https://godbolt.org/g/E84ud4.

Custom `swap` does not call any `delete` and might be therefore more efficient. I guess this is the reason why `std::unique_ptr` provides custom `std::swap` specialization.

**UPDATE**

It seems that Intel and Clang compilers are able to optimize out deletion of null pointers, however GCC isn't. See [Why GCC doesn't optimize out deletion of null pointers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689690/why-gcc-doesnt-optimize-out-deletion-of-null-pointers-in-c) for details.

**UPDATE**

It seems that with GCC, we can prevent invoking `delete` operator by rewriting `X` as follows:

```
 // X& operator=(X&& rhs) noexcept { if (i_) delete i_; i_ = rhs.i_;
 //                                  rhs.i_ = nullptr; return *this; }
    ~X() { if (i_) delete i_; }
```