# What does `std::swap` do when applied to these objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, swap, copy-and-swap

The code

```
using namespace std;

class A 
{
private:
  vector<int> a;
public:
  A(vector<int> x):a(x){}
  string toString()
  {
      string s;
      for (auto& element : a)
      {
          s += to_string(element) + " ";
      }
      return s;
  }
};

int main()
{
    A a1({1,2,3});
    A a2({11,12,13});

    cout << "a1 = " << a1.toString() << "\n";
    cout << "a2 = " << a2.toString() << "\n";
    
    swap(a1,a2);
    
    cout << "a1 = " << a1.toString() << "\n";
    cout << "a2 = " << a2.toString() << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

outputs as expected

```
a1 = 1 2 3                                                                                                            
a2 = 11 12 13                                                                                                         
a1 = 11 12 13                                                                                                         
a2 = 1 2 3
```

From [cplusplus.com > std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) under **complexity**

> **Non-array:** Constant: Performs exactly one construction and two assignments (although notice that each of these operations works on its own complexity).
>
> **Array:** Linear in N: performs a swap operation per element.

Does it mean that `std::swap` when applied to `a1` and `a2` only swaps the pointers to the arrays `[1,2,3]` and `[11,12,13]` but does not copy any `int` or anything else?

**What exactly does `std::swap` does when applied to two objects of the class `A`?**

Assuming the `std::swap` copies all elements of the array, should I write a `static A::swap` function, using `vector::swap` whose time complexity is constant (from [cplusplus.com > vector::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/)) meaning that it only swaps the pointers?

---

> [..] want to add a note that the semantics of `std::swap` is changed in C++17. So it might be a good idea to mention compiler, version of it and what standard you target.

I was hoping that a simple looking question would not have brought about complexities about C++ standards and compiler versions. I typically compile my code in C++11. For the sake of completeness here is the gcc version on my laptop.

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: I'll admit defeat regarding the overload issue. But then want to add a note that the semantics of [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is changed in C++17. So it might be a good idea to mention compiler, version of it and what standard you target. And what you ask about is directly influenced by that semantic change in C++17.

Comment: Related: [Move semantics == custom swap function obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416385/move-semantics-custom-swap-function-obsolete); [How to overload std::swap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562/how-to-overload-stdswap)

Answer (score 5):

There is a requirement that the type parameter to the `std::swap` template
is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable. This suggests that the `swap` can be written roughly as (a few bits omitted)

```
void swap(T &a, T &b) {
   T tmp{std::move(a)};
   a = std::move(b);
   b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

For your example class, it'll invoke the default move ctor/move assignment operators (edit: of `A`) a few times and they in turn will invoke those of `std::vector`.
IOW, you can expect your program to be reasonably efficient as is.

Alternatively, you can define a non-member `swap` function in the same namespace as `A` and call explicitly `std::swap` with vector parameters. Or call directly `std::vector::swap`.

Comment: It should be noted that the move constructible and assignable parts only came in the C++17 standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude These requirements exist before C++17. C++17 excludes this function from overload resolution if these requirements are not met.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your compiler and the classes/types you are using the swap function will either copy one of the classes, or use the move constructor/assignment (C++11 and upwards) (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Your class only consists of a vector and for vector classes this move constructor does what you refer to as simply "swapping pointers", so it will be very quick. Just be aware that implementing e.g. a copy constructor will delete the implicitly-declared move constructor which makes this 'magic' happen!! (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor)

While looking at the swap function independently, I'm giving you an avalanche of followup-insights:
One of the most famous uses of the swap-function happens in the copy-and-swap idiom (https://progdoo.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/c11-copy-and-swap-idiom/). This works most efficiently with implemented move-constructors/assignments.