# How to add std::swap for my template class?

Tags: c++, class, stl, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to provide a swap function for my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380862/how-to-provide-a-swap-function-for-my-class)

There are some questions about this, but a lot of contradictions (person A giving solution A' with many upvotes with person B saying it's UB) or "only works if the compiler supports ADL" is answered.

So, say I have the following template (container) class:

```
template<typename T>
class C {
    // ...
    void swap(C<T>& y) throw(); // C x; x.swap(y);
}
```

then what is the correct way to make sure this (example) code works:

```
C<int> x, y;
std::swap(x, y);
```

Please give your answer for C++03, and if it still works in C++0x, even better!

Comment: Xeo: That's about a non-template class.

Comment: @night: No, it counts for every class.

Comment: Xeo: "3) Explicit specialization of std::swap." I don't see that happening with a template class.

Comment: @night: Yeah, since you can't partially specialize, what is left? Free function in your namespace, 2) in my answer. I amended it to explicitly state that now, though.

Comment: Xeo: That depends on ADL, is there any other way?

Comment: @night: Yes, put it in global namespace, but... just do what everyone does and you'll be fine. Also, providing a namespace for your stuff is generally good.

Comment: Generally, but this is a single concept with a single class in a single header. Is there any way to use this without using a namespace? Or `namespace C { /* ... */ } using namespace C;`?

Comment: That's the same as putting it directly in global namespace. :P

Comment: But now ADL will find my swap... right?

Comment: Your swap will also be found without ADL if you put it directly in global namespace, I believe. Let me test that. **Edit**: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are not allowed to overload functions in the std-namespace.**

Declare swap as a free function, overloaded in the same namespace as your class `C`:

```
 template<class T>
 void swap(C<T>& x, C<T>& y) { x.swap(y); }
```

The right way to swap is to import std::swap and use a non-qualified version (which is retreieved via namespace-based Koenig lookup):

```
 template<class T>
 void dostuff(T x, T y) {
    ...
    using std::swap;
    swap(x,y);
    ...
 }
```

That will use C::swap if x and are C, and std::swap for types that do not have their own swap.

*(The import of std::swap like above is only necessary in template functions where the type is not known. If you know you have a C, then you can use x.swap(y) right away w/o problems.)*

Comment: This forces me to put my `C` in a namespace. Or is a anonymous namespace sufficient?

Comment: @nightcracker: No, as every translation unit will now have your class in a different namespace, afaik.

Comment: @nightcracker: You can have C in the global namespace if you like, or an anonymous namespace, if you only use C (and it's swap) in a single translation unit. The point is that C and it's free swap-function must be in the same one (i.e. don't put anything in the std namespace).