# Cannot open source file "swap.h"

Tags: c++

I'm in the process of completing a school assignment and I'm having a problem using swap.h. I know that normally things like this are external dependencies but in Visual Studio 2010, I don't see it in my list of external dependencies. I'm not sure where to find it or how to add it to the list so I can use the swap function. Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction here?

```
#include "swap.h"
```

That's just to simply show how I'm attempting to include the file.

Comment: Take the line out and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so I can use the swap function

[**`std::swap()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) from [the C++ Algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is

- Defined in header `<algorithm>` (until C++11)
- Defined in header `<utility>` (since C++11)

In Visual Studio 2010, you probably need:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

---

#### Following comments:

Call `std::swap()` thus, to enable [argument-dependent-lookup](/questions/tagged/argument-dependent-lookup):

```
using std::swap;
swap(theArray[index], theArray[nextIndex]);
```

**Further reading:** [How to provide a `swap` function for my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6380862/78845)

Comment: Thank you for your solution but when I do this, I'm getting an error when calling the swap function.

Comment: I'm calling it like this: swap(theArray[index], theArray[nextIndex]);

Comment: It's saying the identifier "swap" is undefined.

Comment: `swap` is in the `std` namespace, use `std::swap` (do not use `using namespace std`, it's not good practice)

Comment: @StephenLin Thank you, this fixed the problem. I appreciate all the help from everyone.

Comment: Usually he best way to call swap is with `using std::swap;` ... `swap(a,b);`. Then the type can implement it as an overload found via ADL. The only reason not to do that, is if you're swapping a type whose implementer (for some strange reason) has given it a non-member function named `swap` that does something other than swapping.

Comment: @SteveJessop yes, but that might be bit too much for a school assignment...I doubt this is supposed to robust against new user-defined types defining `swap` overloads in their own namespaces...good point though, in general

Comment: @StephenLin: you're right, but unless the questioner doesn't have time to look up the meaning of what I'm talking about, then there's no time like now to start doing things properly :-) I just mentioned it because the questioner doesn't specify the type of the objects swapped. If it's some type out of a library then there's a genuine risk that `std::swap` will be inefficient and can throw. If it's `int` then fully-qualified `std::swap` is absolutely fine.

Comment: @StephenLin: Additionally, we want StackOverflow answers to be useful to future visitors as well as original posters.

Comment: @Johnsyweb hah no worries, I definitely agree :) it was just the easiest thing to explain in a comment so the OP could compile

Comment: @StephenLin: Indeed. I'm always happy for [people to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) my posts if it helps someone solve a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

include `<algorithm>` to get `std::swap`