# custom iterator for 2D array

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

i tried to make custom iterator for 2D array to iterate it by column. what i want to achieve by this test is to manipulate 2d array values.
for example this script with produce an out put:

> ```
> 0 1 2
> 3 4 5
> 6 7 8
> ```

by help of column iterator and `std::reverse` i can manipulate 2d array to get the out put like this

> ```
> 6 1 2
> 3 4 5
> 0 7 8
> ```

however. same result can be done by std::swap. so i repeated the test script by swap but it fails.

my question, is the swap for any iterator class is just dummy member function?

```
template<typename Container>
class Columniterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
    typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<Container>()[0][0])>::type>
{
    using iterator = typename Container::iterator;
    using  type = typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<Container>()[0][0])>::type;
public:

    Columniterator(iterator _it, size_t _i)
        : it(_it), i(_i)
    {}
```

....

a lot of code bla bla

....

```
    void swap(Columniterator& other)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(it, other.it);
    }
private:
    iterator it;
    size_t i;
};
```

test code

```
    //std::reverse(Columniterator<Container>(container.begin(),0), Columniterator<Container>(container.end(), 0)); // passed
    std::swap(Columniterator<Container>(container.begin(),0), Columniterator<Container>(container.end(), 0)); // failed
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't implement `swap` at global scope, you implemented `swap` within the class.

If you implement a proper `swap` it can be made to work. See [how to provide a swap function for my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380862/how-to-provide-a-swap-function-for-my-class)

Comment: still swap won't work

Answer (score 3):

Your test try to swap temporaries; use variable instead:

```
auto begin0 = begin(matrix, 0);
auto end0 = end(matrix, 0);

begin0.swap(end0);
```

or provide `swap` overload with rvalue reference.

Comment: its your code i just tried to add swap to it. but it seems won't be

Comment: @MORTAL: You may add info about what doesn't work: No info in the Question and in both answers. It would help us to help you.