# Name hiding by using declaration

Tags: c++, swap, using, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

```
#include <iostream>

struct H
{
    void swap(H &rhs); 
};    

void swap(H &, H &)
{
    std::cout << "swap(H &t1, H &t2)" << std::endl;
}

void H::swap(H &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(*this, rhs);
}


int main(void)
{
    H a;
    H b;

    a.swap(b);
}
```

And this is the result:

```
swap(H &t1, H &t2)
```

In the code above, I try to define a swap function of `H`. In the function `void H::swap(H &rhs)`, I use an using declaration to make the name std::swap visible. If there isn't an using declaration, the code cannot be compiled because there is no usable swap function with two parameters in class `H`.

I have a question here. In my opinion, after I used the using declaration -- `using std::swap`, it just make the std::swap -- the template function in STL visible. So I thought that the swap in STL should be invoked in `H::swap()`. But the result showed that the `void swap(H &t1, H &t2)` was invoked instead.

So here is my question:

1. Why can't I invoke swap without a using declaration？(I guess it is because there is no swap function with two parameters in the class. But I am not sure. )
2. Why will the swap of my definition be invoked instead of the STL swap in the `H::swap`?

Comment: You left a lot of irrelevant (distracting) code in your question. Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: I'd write an answer, but I'm not sure about the technicalities of argument-dependent lookup. It should be a pretty googlable term, though. (Your suspicion 1 is correct; overload resolution doesn't venture outside the class when a name is found in it.)

Comment: @WingCuengRay I removed all of that code for a reason - it was completely irrelevant to, and distracting from, the question. You don't need any of the constructors or operators to demonstrate the problem you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Why can't I invoke swap without a using declaration？

We start in the nearest enclosing scope and work our way outwards until we find something. With this:

```
void H::swap(H &rhs)
{
    swap(*this, rhs);
}
```

Unqualified `swap` finds `H::swap()`. Then we do argument-dependent lookup. But the rule there is, from [[basic.lookup.argdep]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#basic.lookup.argdep-3):

> Let *X* be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let *Y* be the lookup set produced by
>   argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If *X* contains
>   — a declaration of a class member, or
>   — a block-scope function declaration that is not a *using-declaration*, or
>   — a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>   then *Y* is empty. Otherwise *Y* is the set of declarations found in the namespaces associated with the argument types as described below. [...]

Since the unqualified lookup set finds a class member, the argument-dependent lookup set is empty (that is, it doesnt find `swap(H&, H&)`).

> 2. Why will the swap of my definition be invoked instead of the STL swap in the `H::swap`?

When you add:

```
void H::swap(H &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(*this, rhs);
}
```

now unqualified `swap` finds `std::swap()` and **not** `H::swap()`, since the former is declared in a more inner scope. `using std::swap;` does not match any of the criteria in the above-stated rule that would lead to *Y* being empty (it's not a class member, it *is* a *using-declaration*, and it is a function template). As a result, the argument-dependent lookup set does include declarations found in associated namespaces - which includes `swap(H&, H&)` (since `H` is in the global namespace). We end up with two overload candidates - and yours is preferred since it's the non-template.

---

See [Xeo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380882/2069064) on the preferred way to add swap to your class. Basically, you want to write:

```
struct H {
    friend void swap(H&, H&) { ... }
};
```

This will be found by ADL (and only by ADL). And then whenever anybody *calls* swap correct:

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

Lookup will find yours where appropriate.

Comment: "Then we do argument-dependent lookup" ... "we don't do argument-dependent lookup" confusing answer!

Comment: Do you mean that The rule of [basic.lookup.argdep] dosen't apply because  unqualified swap only finds the `std::swap` instead of `H::swap` in the inner scope, so both of the two candidates are found and the best matching is applied because of ADL? However, `void swap(H &, H &)` is defined in global scope instead of a namespace. It seems that ADL is not     suitable without a namespace.

Comment: @WingCuengRay ADL looks in the associated namespaces of the argument types. In this case, that associated namespace is the global namespace. ADL is only about lookup - overload resolution is a separate process.

Comment: by the way, which book are the words -- "Let X ..."cited from?

Comment: @WingCuengRay The C++ standard, latest working draft. I added a link to a nice online linkable version.

Comment: Now I know that It is through the ADL that `void swap(H &, H &)` can be found.  But I still have some misunderstanding of your words -- "Now, the earlier rule doesn't apply". Why? Does it break any of the three rules listed in [basic.lookup.argdep] above? If yes, which one?

Comment: @WingCuengRay It simply doesn't fit any of the criteria. See updated wording.