# this code compiles but doesnt show output when it runs (c++) in visual studio 2015 community

Tags: c++

```
#include <conio.h>  // include conio.h file
#include <iostream.h> // or #include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int cout = 5;   
    cout << cout;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen ??

The code compiles correctly but it does not give expected output when it runs

This does not give the output 5 and all other stuff

It also does not give a warning.

Comment: Rename your variable from `cout` to something else.

Comment: Do note `<iostream.h>` is not standard C++.  The the standard C++ headers have no `.h`.  `<iostream.h> => <iostream>`.

Comment: It would be more interesting of a question if the program had `using namespace std;`

Comment: What do you wanted to do?

Comment: What is `<conio.h>`? What is `<iostream.h>`? And why do you expect this code to produce any output? It does not contain any output-producing statements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following line declares an `int` that happens to be called `cout` (it is not the `std::cout` stream)

```
int cout = 5;
```

The `<<` operator peforms a bit shift.

So

```
cout << cout;
```

is only performing a bit shift and not storing the result.

---

To clarify, have a look at the following program:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int cout = 5;
    auto shiftedval = cout << cout;
    std::cout << "cout's value is " << cout << ", and the result of the bit shift is " << shiftedval << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

It will output:

```
cout's value is 5, and the result of the bit shift is 160
```

---

What is happening behind the scenes is that `operator<<` [has been overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) to take an `ostream` on the left hand side.

By including `iostream` you get this function and the compiler will know what you mean if you have an `ostream` to the left of the `<<` operator.

Without a library the `<<` would just simply have been a [bitwise shift operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators).

---

Also note that if you had [ill-advisedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1460794) included `using namespace std;` or `using std::cout` then `cout` would then mean `ostream` and `<<` would trigger a call to the library `operator<<` function. If after adding the `using` declaration above you include another declaration of `cout` the newly declared name [will hide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35895314/1460794) the previous declaration and `cout` will now be considered an `int` again and we're back to the bit shift operator functionality being used.

Example:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; // using std:: at global scope

int main()
{
    int cout = 5;
    auto shiftedval = cout << cout;

    //the following will not compile, cout is an int:
    cout << "cout's value is " << cout << ", and the result of the bit shift is " << shiftedval << '\n';

    //but we can get the cout from the global scope and the following will compile
    ::cout << "cout's value is " << cout << ", and the result of the bit shift is " << shiftedval << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i did not understand ... please could you explain a bit more

Answer (score 3):

You are naming your variable `cout`, which you are confusing with `std::cout`. Your example preforms a [bit shift operation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators). Try this instead :

```
int main()
{
    int cout = 5;   
    std::cout << cout;

    return 0;
}
```

Better yet, name your variable anything else to avoid the confusion :

```
int main()
{
    int foo = 5;   
    std::cout << foo;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly declare the `std` namespace, either by including `using namespace std;` in your code or calling `std::cout` then `cout` resolves to the local variable `cout` in your `main()` function.

Even if you *do* declare `using namespace std;` `cout` will still resolve to the local variable instead - this is one reason why a lot of people, books, and tutorials will recommend that you explicitly write `std::whatever` instead of using the namespace.