# How to write a standard-like function that has high overload priority

Tags: c++, c++11, ambiguous, argument-dependent-lookup

In a generic function I use the following idiom,

```
template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first){
    ... other stuff here...
    using std::copy;
    copy(first, second, d_first);
}
```

*`do_something` is a generic function that shouldn't know anything specific about any other libraries (except perhaps `std::`).*

Now suppose I have several iterator in my namespace `N`.

```
namespace N{

  struct itA{using trait = void;};
  struct itB{using trait = void;};
  struct itC{using trait = void;};

}
```

An I want to overload copy for these iterators in this namespace.
Naturally I would do:

```
namespace N{
    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first){
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However when I call `do_something` with `N::A`, `N::B` or `N::C` argument I get "ambiguous call to copy" even though these are in the same namespace as `N::copy`.

**Is there a way to win over `std::copy` in the context of the original function above?**

I though that if I put constrains over the template arguments then `N::copy` would be preferred.

```
namespace N{
    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2, typename = typename SomeN1::trait>
    SomeN2 copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first){
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't help.

**What other workarounds can I try for the generic call to copy to prefer to a copy in the namespace of arguments rather than `std::copy`.**

Complete code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
namespace N{
  struct A{};
  struct B{};
  struct C{};
}

namespace N{
    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first){
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    }
}

template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first){
    using std::copy;
    copy(first, second, d_first); // ambiguous call when It is from namespace N (both `std::copy` and `N::copy` could work.
}

int main(){
    N::A a1, a2, a3;
    do_something(a1, a2, a3); 
}
```

A typical error message is

`error: call of overloaded ‘copy(N::A&, N::A&, N::A&)’ is ambiguous`

---

**Am I right to think that C++ Concepts will help here by preferring function calls with more contraints than less constraints?**

Comment: Not a dupe, but [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953684/9593596).

Comment: Obviously the error comes from always doing `using std::copy;`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, sure, but that (`using std::X; X(a, b, c);`) is a common way to make `copy` work with things like pointers (that don't have a namespace themselves).

Comment: @alfC Your `N::copy` is also a function template that has no arguments associated with namespace `N`. Hence, it is not better than `std::copy` for the purpose of overload resolution.

Comment: No, the standard way is to use `std::copy` directly :p

Comment: it's crude but...a macro might work. redefine copy to another name.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, if I use `std::copy` then there is no chance the special version of `copy` is called. The only way would be to overload `std::copy` (in the namespace `std`) which I don't know if it is allowed.

Comment: How about using the SFINAE template, and in `do_something`, use `using namespace std; using N::copy;`?

Comment: And by having the `using`, you make sure that you have an ambiguity with ADL for your namespace fucntions.

Comment: @geza please, no using namepsace std.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin , that's a good point, actually if I have three versions of copy that force to use the types explicitly then I don't have this problem  `auto copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, A d_first)`  `auto copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, B d_first)` `auto copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, C d_first)`.

Comment: @geza, the problem is that `do_something` is a template function that doesn't know about the namespace `N` or the library `N`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: what's the problem with it in this scenario? It is local to a function, which only contains `copy`. I don't see any problems with this.

Comment: @alfC Yep, introducing an argument from namespace `N` enables ADL.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin the issue is then `int*` doesn't work anymore with the class.

Comment: @alfC I might have a solution to decouple the do something function and the namespace/iterators; will write an answer in a few hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `copy()` as a [public friend function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5695548/9883438) in your iterator classes. 
This works kind of as a replacement for partial specialization (which is impossible for functions), so that they will be preferred by overload resolution as they are more specialized:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace N
{
    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first)
    {
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
        return d_first;
    }

    template <class T>
    struct ItBase
    {
        template <class SomeN2>
        friend SomeN2 copy(T first, T last, SomeN2 d_first)
        {
            return N::copy(first, last, d_first);
        }
    };

    struct A : ItBase<A>{};
    struct B : ItBase<B>{};
    struct C : ItBase<C>{};
}

template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first){
    using std::copy;
    copy(first, second, d_first);
}

int main(){
    N::A a1, a2, a3;
    std::cout << "do something in N:" << std::endl;
    do_something(a1, a2, a3); 

    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v2(3);
    std::cout << "do something in std:" << std::endl;
    do_something(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v2));
    for (int i : v2)
        std::cout << i;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

See [this demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk-7vnT7E) to verify that it works.

I introduced a common base class that declares the necessary friends for all of your iterators. So, instead of declaring a tag, as you tried, you just have to inherit from `ItBase`.

Note: If `N::copy()` is supposed to work with only these iterators in `N`, it might not be needed anymore as these friend functions will be publicly visible in `N` anyway (as if they were free functions).

---

### Update:

In the comments, it has been suggested, if the iterators in `N` have a common base class anyway, to just declare `N::copy` with this base class, e.g.

```
namespace N
{
    template <class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy(ItBase first, ItBase last, SomeN2 d_first) { ... }
}
```

Unfortunately, this would have the opposite effect of the desired one: `std::copy` will always be preferred over `N::copy` because if you pass an instance of `A`, it would have to be downcasted in order to match `N::copy` while no cast is required for `std::copy`. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/mZtaEV) you can see that obviously `std::copy` is tried to be called (which gives an error because `N::A` lacks some typedefs).

So, you cannot leverage a common base class for the signature of `N::copy`. The one and only reason I used one in my solution was to avoid duplicate code (having to declare the friend function in every iterator class). My `ItBase` does not participate in overload resolution at all.

Note, however, if your iterators happen to have some common members (whether derived from some common base class or not is not important) that you want to use in your implementation of `N::copy`, you can just do that with my solution above like so:

```
namespace N
{
    template <class T>
    struct ItBase
    {
        template <class SomeN2>
        friend SomeN2 copy(T first, T last, SomeN2 d_first)
        {
            first.some_member();
            last.some_member();
            return d_first;
        }
    };

    struct A : ItBase<A>{ void some_member() {} };
    struct B : ItBase<B>{ void some_member() {} };
    struct C : ItBase<C>{ void some_member() {} };
}
```

See [here](https://onlinegdb.com/B1uOZxkVE) how it works.

---

On the same lines, if A, B, C have common behavior then it could be possible to replaced them by common template class parameterized in some way.

```
namespace N
{
    template <class T, int I>
    struct ItCommon
    {
       ...
    };
    using A = ItCommon<double,2>;
    using B = ItCommon<int, 3>;
    using C = ItCommon<char, 5>;
}
...
namespace N{
    template<class T, int I, class Other>
    SomeN2 copy(ItCommon<T, I> first, ItCommon<T, I> last, Other){
        ...
    }
}
```

Since this (non-friend) `copy` function is definitely more constrained than the `std::copy` and because of ADL, it will have high priority when one of the arguments belongs to the `N` namespace. Also, being a non-friend, this `copy` function is an optional component.

Comment: This is an interesting solution and the friend in the base class allows have the coupling between the iterators and the algorithm declared only once. The problem with this is that the `N::iterators` will have to know of all possible algorithms that can implemented `copy`, `fill`, `accumulate`, etc.

Comment: @alfC So you are saying that `copy` was just an example and actually you want to do this with several std algorithms? In that case you have to implement them anyway, so just put them into `ItBase` directly. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Yes, the point is that these iterators will need to know about any special function in advance. Besides that point, this a good alternative design.

Comment: BTW, I think public or private doesn't make a difference here for a friend function. friend functions seem to be always accesible (public).

Comment: your answer inspired me for this yet-another-alternative, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54425412/225186

Comment: @alfC "the point is that these iterartors will need to know about any special function in advance" I don't see the issue with this. You have to provide these "special function's" implementation *somewhere* anyhow. So, if they are especially designed for all iterators inheriting from `ItBase`, why not group them all together inside of `ItBase` as friends?

Comment: sure, that is a possible design. The idea is that I would implement `N::copy` in terms of more fundamental operations (e.g. members) on the iterators A, B, and C. (but still fundamentally different from `std::copy` to need a special implementation.)

Comment: @alfC Ok I see. But if these members are all different for A, B, and C, then you'll have to provide 3 different implementations anyway. If all iterators have the same members, you can access them via the template param `T` that you passed to `ItBase`. Same goes for non member functions or whatever else you have in mind for your implementation of `copy`.

Comment: That's right, I think this is the point, if A, B, C have common interfaces/structure (enough to implement all in the same way in `N::copy`) that means that there might be a common base class OR a common template implementation of A, B, C (parameterized by other class). In that case the arguments of `N::copy` can be either `(iter_base, ...)` or `template T1 ... (iter<T1>, `. Both have higher precedence than `std::copy` in the example. If you agree, please add a note to your answer.

Comment: @alfC see my update. If I misunderstood what you mean, please update your question as well to ellaborate, as this seems to be an important detail in order to give you the answer that you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use another function template name and type discriminators to allow argument-dependent name lookup to find the associated function in the namespace of the arguments:

```
template<class T> struct Tag {};
template<class T> Tag<void> tag(T const&);

template<class It1, class It2>
void mycopy(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first, Tag<void>) {
    std::cout << "std::copy\n";
}

template<class It1, class It2>
void mycopy(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first) {
    mycopy(first, second, d_first, decltype(tag(first)){}); // Discriminate by the type of It1.
}

namespace N{

    struct itA{using trait = void;};
    Tag<itA> tag(itA);

    template<class It1, class It2>
    void mycopy(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first, Tag<itA>) {
        std::cout << "N::mycopy\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    char* p = 0;
    mycopy(p, p, p); // calls std::copy

    N::itA q;
    mycopy(q, q, q); // calls N::mycopy
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to fulfill your requirements:

```
namespace SpecCopy {

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
void copy(A &&a, B &&b, C &&c) {
    std::copy(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b), std::forward<C>(c));
}

}

template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first){
    using namespace SpecCopy;
    copy(first, second, d_first);
}
```

Basically, it depends on ADL. If no function found by ADL, then it will use `SpecCopy::copy`, which is a wrapper to `std::copy`.

---

So, if you do:

```
N::A a1, a2, a3;
do_something(a1, a2, a3);
```

Then `do_something` will call `N::copy`.

---

If you do:

```
std::vector<int> a1, a2;
do_something(a1.begin(), a1.end(), a2.begin());
```

Then `do_something` will call `SpecCopy::copy`, which will call `std::copy`.

---

If you do:

```
int *a1, *a2, *a3;
do_something(a1, a2, a3);
```

Then same thing happens as before: `do_something` will call `SpecCopy::copy`, which will call `std::copy`.

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue ... it ties the general `do_something` to the special code for the iterators ...

Comment: @DanielJour: Can you give an example or more explanation? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @DanielJour , geza, as DanielJour says, `do_something` will need to know about the `SpecCopy` library/namespace. and if you include `SpecCopy` with `do_something` then there is no customization, `N::copy` is never called in this way.

Comment: @alfC: Hmm, I thought that you want an ADL based solution. If iterator is in `namespace N`, and you have a `copy` function in `namespace N`, then with this solution, `N::copy` will be called.

Comment: @alfC: I've edited my answer so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

In c++ 11 you could use tag dispatch. If you can make a little change to your custom iterators things will be a bit simpler to implement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// indicates that the type doesn't have a tag type (like pointers and standard iterators)
struct no_tag{};

namespace detail 
{
    template <typename T>
    auto tag_helper(int) -> typename T::tag;

    template <typename>
    auto tag_helper(long) -> no_tag;
}

// get T::tag or no_tag if T::tag isn't defined.
template <typename T>
using tag_t = decltype(detail::tag_helper<T>(0));

namespace N
{
    struct my_iterator_tag {};
    struct A{ using tag = my_iterator_tag; };
    struct B{ using tag = my_iterator_tag; };
    struct C{ using tag = my_iterator_tag; };
}

namespace N
{
    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy_helper(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first, no_tag)
    {
        std::cout << "calling std::copy\n";
        return std::copy(std::forward<SomeN1>(first), std::forward<SomeN1>(last), std::forward<SomeN2>(d_first));
    }

    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy_helper(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first, my_iterator_tag)
    {
        // your custom copy        
        std::cout << "custom copy function\n";
        return {};
    }

    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first)
    {
        return copy_helper(std::forward<SomeN1>(first), std::forward<SomeN1>(last), std::forward<SomeN2>(d_first), tag_t<SomeN1>{});
    }
}

template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first)
{
    N::copy(first, second, d_first);
}

int main()
{
    N::A a1, a2, a3;
    std::cout << "using custom iterator: ";
    do_something(a1, a2, a3); 

    std::cout << "using vector iterator: ";
    std::vector<int> v;
    do_something(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v));

    std::cout << "using pointer: ";
    int* ptr = new int[10];
    do_something(ptr, ptr + 5, ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

First we change our custom iterators to have a `tag` type (maybe change the name to avoid confusion with `iterator_category`). `tag` can be any type you want, it just has to match the type you use as tag in `copy_helper`.

Next, we define a type that allows us to access this `tag` type, or to fall back to a default type if `tag` doesn't exist. This will help us distinguish between our custom iterators and standard iterators and pointers. The default type I use is `no_tag`. The `tag_t` provides us with this functionality by using SFINAE and overload resolution. We call the function `tag_helper(0)` which has two declarations. The first one returns `T::tag` while the second one returns `no_tag`. Calling `tag_helper(0)` will always try to use the first version because `int` is a better match for `0` than `long`. This means we will always try to access `T::tag` first. However if this isn't possible (`T::tag` is not defined) SFINAE kicks in and skipps `tag_helper(int)` selecting `tag_helper(long)`.

Finally, we just have to implement a copy function for each tag (I called it `copy_helper`) and another copy function as a wrap around for convinience (I used `N::copy`). The wrapper function then creates the proper tag type and calls the correct helper function.

[Here](https://onlinegdb.com/ryb_9K2XN) is a live example.

### Edit

If you move the code around a bit you can disconnect namespace `N` and rely on ADL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// indicates that the type doesn't have a tag type (like pointers and standard iterators)
struct no_tag{};

namespace detail 
{
    template <typename T>
    auto tag_helper(int) -> typename T::tag;

    template <typename>
    auto tag_helper(long) -> no_tag;
}

// get T::tag or no_tag if T::tag isn't defined.
template <typename T>
using tag_t = decltype(detail::tag_helper<T>(0));

namespace N
{
    struct my_iterator_tag {};
    struct A{ using tag = my_iterator_tag; };
    struct B{ using tag = my_iterator_tag; };
    struct C{ using tag = my_iterator_tag; };

    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy_helper(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first, my_iterator_tag)
    {
        // your custom copy        
        std::cout << "custom copy function\n";
        return {};
    }
}

template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
SomeN2 copy_helper(SomeN1 first, SomeN1 last, SomeN2 d_first, no_tag)
{
    std::cout << "calling std::copy\n";
    return std::copy(std::forward<SomeN1>(first), std::forward<SomeN1>(last), std::forward<SomeN2>(d_first));
}

template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first)
{
    copy_helper(std::forward<It1>(first), std::forward<It1>(second), std::forward<It2>(d_first), tag_t<It1>{});
}

int main()
{
    N::A a1, a2, a3;
    std::cout << "using custom iterator: ";
    do_something(a1, a2, a3); 

    std::cout << "using vector iterator: ";
    std::vector<int> v;
    do_something(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v));

    std::cout << "using pointer: ";
    int* ptr = new int[10];
    do_something(ptr, ptr + 5, ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but `do_something` will need to know about the `N` namespace, which might be in a disconnected library.

Comment: @alfC Well you could also move the code from `copy` directly to `do_something` and include the `copy_helper` with the `no_tag` tag in the same library. Then you can rely on ADL again. Your disconnected library has to implement the `copy_helper` with its according tag.

Comment: The Edit is the closest to an answer to the question so far. Note aside, I think the `forward<It1>` is useless unless you pass arguments as `It1&& first`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, building on @paler123, but without checking for an existing type, but checking if `It1`  is a pointer instead:

```
namespace N{
  struct A{};
  struct B{};
  struct C{};
}

namespace N{
    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy(SomeN1, SomeN1, SomeN2 c){
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
        return c;
    }
}
template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first){
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<It1>) {
        std::copy(first, second, d_first);
    }
    else
    {
        copy(first, second, d_first);
    }
}


int main(){
    N::A a1, a2, a3;
    do_something(a1, a2, a3); 

    int* b1, *b2, *b3;

    do_something(b1, b2, b3); 
}
```

Still C++17, but in the case of pointers, we go through the explicit `std::copy` otherwise, we rely on ADL.

In general, your issue is a design problem. You want to use `std::copy` for all cases, except for objects from `N`, and in that case, you hope that ADL will work. But as you forced `std::copy`, you remove the option for proper ADL. You can't have everything and you have to redesign your code.

Comment: Thanks for the option. Pointer types are just an example, other (non-std iterators) will not work now. In other words this forces all iterators and pointer-like iterators to implement `copy` for them, even if `std::copy` would be fine for them.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, I agree. The problem you have, once again, is a design problem. You want to try to rely on ADL in some cases, but not in others. Not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

**(These notes are now integrated in my edit to @sebrockm's answer)**

---

For discussion I will write an answer to my own question with an alternative option.

It is not very nice because it needs to wrap all the `N::` classes in another template class (called `wrap` here). The good thing is that `do_something` nor the `N` classes need to know about the special `N::copy`. The price is that the `main` caller has to explicitly wrap the `N::` classes which is ugly but which is fine from the point of view of coupling because this is the only code that should know about the whole system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace N{
    struct A{};
    struct B{};
    struct C{};
}

namespace N{

    template<class S> struct wrap : S{};

    template<class SomeN1, class SomeN2>
    SomeN2 copy(wrap<SomeN1> first, wrap<SomeN1> last, wrap<SomeN2> d_first)
    {
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
        return d_first;
    }
}

template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first){
    using std::copy;
    copy(first, second, d_first);
}

int main(){
    N::wrap<N::A> a1, a2, a3;
    std::cout << "do something in N:" << std::endl;
    do_something(a1, a2, a3); 

    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v2(3);
    std::cout << "do something in std:" << std::endl;
    do_something(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v2));
    for (int i : v2)
        std::cout << i;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That or the approach with the friend function is probably the best You can get; there aren't any more rules for ADL best viable candidate selection that one could leverage.

Answer (score -2):

Suggest you have a look at the very powerful new [Boost.HOF](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/hof/doc/html/doc/index.html) library.

This function does exactly what you want:

```
#include <boost/hof.hpp>

template<class It1, class It2>
void do_something(It1 first, It1 second, It2 d_first){
    namespace hof = boost::hof;

    auto my_copy = hof::first_of(
    [](auto first, auto second, auto d_first) -> decltype(N::copy(first, second, d_first))
    {
        return N::copy(first, second, d_first);
    },
    [](auto first, auto second, auto d_first) -> decltype(std::copy(first, second, d_first))
    {
        return std::copy(first, second, d_first);
    });
    my_copy(first, second, d_first);
}
```

`hof::first_of` will select the first lambda whose return type is deduced to be the result type of a legal expression.

Comment: This looks like an interesting library. However the problem is that `do_something` still needs to know about the library/namespace `N`.

Comment: @alfC I see. It wasn't clear to me that you're after a general solution for calling `copy`.