# Pimpl idiom and swap

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom

I have several classes that are based on the PIMPL idiom (where a `unique_ptr` refers to the actual implementation struct).

I haven't added a `friend` `swap` function (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695548/public-friend-swap-member-function)) as, to my knowledge, the standard `std::swap` uses move-semantics which would nicely swap out the `unique_ptr`s. So far, so good.

However, I read (the somewhat outdated `Effective C++` from Scott Meyers that says in Item 25:

> However, the default swap implementation might not thrill you. It involves copying three objects: a to temp, b to a, and temp to b. [...] For some types, the default swap puts you on the fast track to the slow lane. Foremost among such types are those consisting primarily of a pointer to another type that contains the real data. A common manifestation of this design is the "pimpl" idiom.

After which he also suggest to specialize `std::swap` as well.

My question is whether this still holds in C++11. It seems that the C++11 `swap` works just fine for pimpl'd classes. I understand that adding a `friend` `swap` allows the STL to use argument dependent lookup and so on, but I prefer to keep my classes as lean as possible.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is whether this still holds in C++11.

Only to a much lesser degree.

Since introduction of move semantics in C++11, the generic swap no longer copies, but moves instead.

Moving is often much closer to optimal swap implementation so much so that one often doesn't need to bother writing a custom implementation. Although it may be close to optimal, in many cases (including the PIMPL case, as demonstrated by [DanielLangr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61892554/2079303)) a custom implementation can be better. Whether it is sufficiently much faster to be beneficial to write a custom one can be determined by measuring the performance.

Comment: I would argue that a custom implementation can be even _significantly_ more optimal in some cases (e.g., see my answer).

Comment: @DanielLangr Relative difference may be significant, but I would still expect the generic swap to be very fast. It just isn't very, very fast. Whether this makes a difference depends a lot on how much of the time you are going to spend swapping.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here might be that with PIMPL implemented by `std::unique_ptr`, you basically need to define move constructor/assignment operator and destructor outside of the header file (see Item 22 of Meyers' Effective Modern C++). Then, `std::swap` does not "see" these definitions and a compiler cannot optimize-away unnecessary operations such as settings of null pointer that won't be used anymore, calling of `operator delete` with null pointer argument, etc. It will just generate 4 `call` instructions, since it has no other option.

Consider a [simple demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P4zNfD) for this class:

```
class X
{
    public: 
        X(X&&);
        X& operator=(X&&);
        ~X();

        void swap(X& other) { std::swap(pimpl_, other.pimpl_); }

    private:
        class Impl;
        std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl_;
};
```

The assembly generated by GCC with `-O3` for swapping of two `X` objects by using `std::swap` was as follows:

```
f1(X&, X&):
        push    r12
        mov     r12, rdi
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsi
        mov     rsi, rdi
        sub     rsp, 24
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]
        call    X::X(X&&)
        mov     rsi, rbp
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    X::operator=(X&&)
        lea     rsi, [rsp+8]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    X::operator=(X&&)
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]
        call    X::~X() [complete object destructor]
        add     rsp, 24
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
        mov     rbp, rax
        jmp     .L2
f1(X&, X&) [clone .cold]:
.L2:
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]
        call    X::~X() [complete object destructor]
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    _Unwind_Resume
```

While the assembly generated for the same operation by using `X::swap` was:

```
f2(X&, X&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], rax
        ret
```

The latter is obviously optimal, since it involves only instructions necessary for swapping two regular pointers (hidden behind `std::unique_ptr` in our case).

---

Moreover, even for empty `X::Impl` class, the generated assembly of the involved special member functions has many instructions:

```
X::X(X&&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], 0
        ret
X::operator=(X&&):
        push    r12
        mov     r12, rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], 0
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     QWORD PTR [r12], rax
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .L7
        mov     esi, 1
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
.L7:
        mov     rax, r12
        pop     r12
        ret
X::~X() [base object destructor]:
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .L12
        mov     esi, 1
        jmp     operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
.L12:
        ret
```